# How to interpret one character at a time using the Win32 API

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

I am currently learning how to properly use the windows console api (windows.h). I am practicing with some basic menu selection via key press detection (Up, Down, etc).

I was wondering if it would be possible (and feasible) to manipulate the user's key press in a way that special characters (Up, Down, etc) trigger special functions, while other inputs (alphanumerics, '?'s, etc) get written to the console input buffer.

Basically: ok, user pressed a key. It was the up arrow, so lets highlight the menu selection above current. Oh, this time it was a letter, lets add that to the input buffer.

I have searched around for tutorials (and more importantly, examples), but haven't really found many so any resources would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use ReadConsoleInput or PeekConsoleInput API to read those data. For menu based selection you will have to use SetConsoleTextAttribute, SetConsoleCursorPosition etc to achieve it

Comment: Would you happen to know of some resources other than the msdn docs (going through all of those now)? I like to have as many examples at my disposal as possible for me to look through.

Comment: This one should be good enough for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u68ouf-kqQ4

Comment: The more I read through the msdn docs the more sense it all makes, but I'm still a novice

Comment: Console programs are meant to be simple. There is a set of Windows specific functions you can use to mess around with console programs. You might want to skip console programs and go to winapi Window program. Catch `WM_xxx` key messages instead.